# I want sum of a column in some other column but based on condition of other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, time-series

I have a data frame given below

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

```
example for year 2016 'div' should only have sum of 'avg_coef' across only 2016 
and same for 2017 'div' should only have sum of 'avg_coef' across only 2017 and not any other value
```

I have almost achieved this by applying lambda but when applying it is only working for the last year in the loop and assigning other value in div as 0 as it move ahead in the loop,
below is the code and output it is generating

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

some how it is only working for last year which is 2021,
please also suggest you have a more optimized way of doing it,
Thanks you all

Comment: Please, see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/14627505) and provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here is how to make a good one [in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/14627505).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html)

```py
df['div'] = df.groupby('Year')['avg_coef'].transform(sum)
```